# c++: How to store the rest of the string in a variable?

Tags: c++, storage

Hey guys I have a question about storing the output to a variable. Let's say I have 3 variables defined as follows:

```
float num, 
string units, 
string rest;
```

and the user enters this in the console:

```
 12.2
 mg 
 Vitamin
```

I know if I want to store it in variables, I have to do the following:

```
cin >> num >> units >> rest;
```

But let's say the user enters Vitamin A instead of Vitamin.

And the I want to store the rest of the string after mg into 'rest' variable.
how do I do that?

I did the following:

```
cin >> num >> units;
getline(cin,rest); //stores the rest of the string into rest
```

But this also stores the space character after `mg` namely if I output `rest`, it would output `" Vitamin A"`. I don't want this space in the beginning. How do I accomplish this?

I know it's long but I hope I made it clear.
Any help or suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can skip whitespace by using `std::ws`

```
cin >> num >> units;
ws(cin);
getline(cin, rest);
```

You can see a live working example here: [ignore leading whitespace](http://ideone.com/oqXhPd)